# export report in plain xml format jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Hi I already know that we can export data in XML format from jasper. But it is returning jasper tag as well which i don't want. I need only plain xml form. is it possible ? if yes then how?

I am generating xml format through below statement:

```
         jrExporter = new JRXmlExporter();
         jrExporter.setParameter(JRXmlExporterParameter.IS_EMBEDDING_IMAGES, Boolean.FALSE);
         response.setContentType("application/xml");
         jrExporter.setParameter(JRXmlExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
         jrExporter.setParameter(JRXmlExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, response.getOutputStream());
         jrExporter.exportReport();
```

Hoping some attribute need to set before exporting, but don't know which one.

Comment: Can you illustrate your question with sample of resulting (generated by code) XML file?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misunderstanding for the JRXmlExporter. JasperReport does not support a data extract of the report via XML. The JRXmlExporter exports the generated report output ie the exact layout specification for each page and element. Also, everything is handled as plain text, so all information if a field was a date or a number is not available.

If you wish to export the data only as XML structure you would need to implement a custom exporter. In order to do so you'd need to define a logic that translates layout structures back into data structures. Based on my research, this can be partially achieved when:

- you limit the scope of the report (ie tables, groups, lists) - some recognisable structure
- you could also utilize custom properties on fields and bands to maintain information such as data type etc.